# How to understand "that was my friends' nickname for me" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I'm Moony -- that was my friends' nickname for me at school.

The sentence confuses me. Is 'Moony' the nickname of his friends or his? I interpret it as: "his friends gave him the nickname Moony" or "He was addressed with the nickname Moony among his friends". What's the correct way to understand it?

Comment: The person's friends at school called them (Singular they. I am reluctant to use "he/him/his" since the gender is not specified) "Moony".

Comment: He was addressed **with** the nickname "Moony" (not **as**).  He was addressed **as** "Moony"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things make it clear that "Moony" was the nickname of the author / first person:

1. He begins by saying "**I'm** Moony" so he is talking about *his* nickname.
2. It says it was his friends' nickname ***for*** him. If it was the nickname by which the writer's friend was called, it would simply say "it was my friend's nickname".
3. It says "my **friends'** nickname for me", not "my **friend's** nickname for me. The placement of the apostrophe indicates that many friends called him by this nickname, not just one. All of his friends cannot have the same nickname.

It is worth noting that the *true* definition of a "nickname" is a name *given* to a person by others. Some internet applications use the term "nickname" for a pseudonym that you choose yourself and as such the meaning may have shifted slightly in modern use. However, some nicknames given to others are pejorative - not something one would choose to be called.

Comment: What would you take if it's written as: "it was my friend's nickname for me at school"?

Comment: @dan Same. Because it is *for* me. I was just pointing out something very obvious and on topic that had been missed.